# Push an object into the object list object

Tags: javascript

The simplest question ever, and I did not find right answer yet.

Got object list: `object_list = {}`

Got object: `object_x = {...}`

How do I add `object_x` to `object_list[objects_x]`?

I tried: `object_list[objects_x][object_list[objects_x].length] = object_x`, but `object_list[objects_x].length` is undefined.

`push()` does not work either.

Do I really need to define external counter for that?

**PLEASE NOT THAT I MEAN LIST OF LISTS OF OBJECTS. NOTE THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN `objects_x` and `object_x`.**

There is no simple solution like in PHP where you simply `$array['something'][] = $somedata` ?

Comment: it's `objects_x` and it is a list of `object_x` objects, not single object.

Comment: It sounds like you want an array (of which `push` IS a method) rather than an object.

Comment: I need it to be associative.

Comment: Surely if you need it to be associative then you must have some requirement for the *names* of the properties (which seems to be what you're lacking at the moment). It really looks like your code could be refactored to use an array.

Comment: what is it that you want to be associative? object_list or object_list.objects_x?

Comment: both, it is only an example, real names of first level objects are "shelfs" "sectors" "images" and "additional", at it may grow up in time, so I need to keep those lists as names to be able to act on them after sending it to the server as json encoded object.

Comment: Clearly you're coming from PHP and are now trying to make all other languages have the same behavior as PHP. I apologize if I'm wrong, but the unjustified criticism you're throwing at JavaScript below means you're somebody who thinks the crap in PHP is the only right way to do things.

Comment: @Erik Allik That is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base assumption is wrong.

This:

```
var object_list = {}
```

Is **not** a list. It's not an array and you can't reference its items by index, thus it also does not have `.length` property.

What you are after is a plain array:

```
var object_list = [];
```

Now you can push items into it:

```
object_list.push(object_x);
```

Edit: based on your comments and edits, I think what you're really after are couple of helper functions:

```
function AddToList(list, item) {
    var counter = 0;
    for (var key in list)
        counter++;
    var key = "item_index_" + counter;
    list[key] = item;
}

function GetItemByIndex(list, index) {
    var counter = 0;
    var existingKey = "";
    for (var key in list) {
        if (counter == index) {
            existingKey = key;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return (existingKey.toString().length > 0) ? list[existingKey] : null;
}
```

Having those, you can have such a code now:

```
var mainList = {};
var newItem = { "foo": "bar" };
AddToList(mainList, newItem);
var dummy = GetItemByIndex(mainList, 0)["foo"]; //will contain "bar"
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/L5RNF/).

Comment: No, because I need it to be 2 level, not only 1. A list of lists.

Comment: @FlashThunder so you can have array of arrays: `var object_list = []; object_list[0] = []; object_list[0].push(object_x);`. The main difference is that in array, you reference items by index and not by a key.

Comment: They are still not associative. I need it to send data to the server to save it. It has to be associative to be understandable and to be able to define only some lists and not all of them at all requests.

Comment: @FlashThunder right, but by using associative collection, you lose the ability to use index, length or push items. You can't eat the cake and leave it whole. :)

Comment: No way to simply add an object to an object? That is really weird.

Comment: @Flash not by using `.push()`, as other tried to explain just assign an object to the collection by using a key.

Comment: Well... seems like there is no other way than to define array objects_x and then to add it to final object_list like that. I am really dissappointed about how this works in js.

Comment: I will accept Your answer, as it is what I was asking for. But there seems to be easier to simply make an object of arrays and to push().

Comment: @FlashThunder not really, that's just how JavaScript works. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
object_list['object_x'] = object_x;
// or
object_list.object_x = object_x;

console.log(object_list.object_x === object_list['object_x'])
```

How to work with objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: It's not an answer to my question. I need it to be list of lists of objects not list of objects. Please note the difference between `objects_x` and `object_x`

Answer (score 1):

When you create a variable like `var stuff = {}`, you're creating an empty object literal, it has no attributes (properties or methods) other than what it inherits from `Object`. If you want to keep objects stored in various lists in this object you need to first create those lists.

```
var stuff = { shelves: [], selectors: [], images: [], additional: [] };
```

Now you can add whatever you want to those lists as much as you want.

```
var image = { src: '/path/to/image.jpg' };
stuff.images.push(image);
```

You can add more lists to `stuff` whenever like by just setting the new property on `stuff`.

```
stuff.some_other_list = []
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't accept two answers :( But `+1` because I will use this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested use object, not array, you can use like this:

```
var object_list = {};
var object_x = {'prop1':'val1'};

// add object
object_list.myobj = object_x;

// for access, same scheme.
object_list.myobj.prop1 = 'valX';

// for loop thru    
for (var key in object_list) {
   var obj = object_list[key];
   obj.prop1 = 'valY';
}
```